# How to render the list in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render the list with vue.js. The data has come from api call.

List rendering is ok, until I try to add `data-feature_id="@{{searched_feature.id}}"` in `li` tag.
When I add it, I got an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:......

```
<div class="search_feature_select">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="searched_feature in searched_features" data-feature_id="@{{searched_feature.id}}" @click="add_to_features_list">
        @{{searched_feature.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I put `searched_feature.id` in `data-feature_id` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add : before the attribute

```
<div class="search_feature_select">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="searched_feature in searched_features" :data-feature_id="searched_feature.id" @click="add_to_features_list">
        {{searched_feature.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'v-bind:' prefix of shorthand ':' before attribute to bind dynamic data.

```
<div class="search_feature_select">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="searched_feature in searched_features" 
    :data-feature_id="searched_feature.id" 
    @click="add_to_features_list">
     {{searched_feature.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See more https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html ***cough*cough***

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    searched_features: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "One"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Two"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Three"
      }      
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    add_to_features_list(){}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="search_feature_select">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="searched_feature in searched_features" :data-feature_id="searched_feature.id" @click="add_to_features_list">
        @{{ searched_feature.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to add the '@' in front of the data-feature_id attribute:

```
<div class="search_feature_select">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="searched_feature in searched_features" :data-feature_id="'@' + searched_feature.id" @click="add_to_features_list">
        {{searched_feature.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```